# what is the usage of page_to_virt?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

i would like to know the usage of `page_to_virt` in the linux kernel like in the line : `memcpy(page_to_virt(&page), (void*) payload, PAGE_SIZE)` please.

i thought about it as a way to copy the content (payload) of the page from the RAM to the virtual memory with an hva but it is still awkward.

Comment: Where in the Linux kernel is this line? I imagine `&page` is the address of a struct page which has meta information for the page itself and `page_to_virt` converts it to a virtual address. `payload` is a separate buffer which is the source of the copy. So yes, copying payload to the page referenced by `&page`.

Comment: There is no such line in the Linux kernel as of today. Care to provide a link to it?

Comment: thanks to you that was my answer @wxz